# Duplicate entry in python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list that contains duplicates, some are exactly the same while others have just a prefix at the beginning.
For example the following entries refer to the same entry:
'user01', 'aa-user01', 'xyz-user01'

I succeeded to remove the entries that are exactly the same but not the ones with a prefix:

```
list = ['user01','user01', 'aa-user01','user02','user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']
list2 = []

for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[i] not in list2:
        list2.append(list[i])

print(list2)
```

I get this:

```
['user01', 'aa-user01', 'user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']
```

The resulat that i want:

```
['user01', 'user02', 'user03']
```

Comment: @Elikill58 That has little to do with the question here.

Comment: What if you had `bcd-user04` but no `user04` in your list? would you want to keep the prefix in this case?

Comment: It might also be helpful to use a set to remove duplicates instead of a for loop.

Comment: @Elikill58 unfortunately that does not answer the question.

Comment: @Altareos i want to remove all prefix and keep just user04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):

    if list[i][list[i].find("user"):] not in list2:
        list2.append(list[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest fix would only consider the token after the `"-"`:

```
for x in list:
    user = x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]
    if user not in list2:
        list2.append(user)
```

Note: you should not shadow built-in names like `list`. Also, contains-checks are expensive for lists, so if you have lots of data, you should consider using a `set` or `dict`.

```
s = set(x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1] for x in lst)
```

Docs:

- [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['user01','user01', 'aa-user01','user02','user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']
list2 = []

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if list1[i] not in list2:
        list2.append(list1[i])

list2 = list(dict.fromkeys(list2))
print(list2)
```

print(list2)

Comment: The duplicate entry are not removed: ['user01', 'aa-user01', 'user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to first remove the prefix using a list comprehension;

**Remove prefix**

```
list = ['user01','user01', 'aa-user01','user02','user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']
list = [i.split('-', 1)[-1] for i in l]
list2 = []

for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[i] not in list2:
        list2.append(list[i])

print(list2)
```

Comment: Tnxs, that works, i just modify the second line :
list = [i.split('-', 1)[-1] for i in list]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a short list comprehension, including:

- `lower()`  -> Ignore case typing (remove if not needed)
- `split()`  -> Removes the prefix
- `set()`    -> Removes duplicates

Your result will be `set([x.lower().split('-', 1)[-1] for x in test_list])` while `test_list` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['user01','user01', 'aa-user01','user02','user02', 'user03', 'xyz-user02']


new_list = [j.split('-')[1] if len(j.split('-'))==2 else j for j in my_list]
    ['user01', 'user01', 'user01', 'user02', 'user02', 'user03', 'user02']#value of new_list
    set(new_list)#output unique values
    {'user01', 'user02', 'user03'}
```